# passing post data to python api to make a twilio phone call

Tags: django, post, twilio

I would like to send some POST data to the url that will be called once the connection is made in a twilio call. Here is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account = "xxx"
token = "xxx"
client = TwilioRestClient(account, token)

server_url = "http://ec2-xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/"
values = dict(name='mytime', \
              appt_time='2:30 PM', \
              location='Arizona Location', \
              client = "Suwanee",
    )
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(server_url, data)

call = client.calls.create(to="123456789", 
                           from_="987654321", 
                           url="ec2-xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hello/")
```

How would I pass the urlencoded `data` to the url as a post?

ec2-xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com is running django, and the this server is able to see the post data when I send the following command:

```
curl -X POST -d "client=mytime+Suwanee&time=2%3A30+PM&location=Suwanee+Location&name=mytime2" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/remind/"
```

How do I replicate this same behavior in the code snippet provided in the very beginning? I want to use POST only (not GET).

Answer (score 0):

For your functionality, I would recommend you to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Example of making a POST request using that library:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can use the request library, but I need to know how to do this using the TwilioRestClient library.